# Php Laravel Comparing 2 Array Values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.4

Is it possible to compare two Array values ?

Say:

```
Array 1>         Array 2>
Values:          Values:
2                 11
36                13
65                11
78                1
```

Code sample:

```
If (Array1 >= Array2){

    echo"Not Available";
    }
    else
    {
    echo"Available";
    }
```

Expected Result:

```
Array ("Not Available",
       "Available",
       "Available",
       "Available")
```

Comment: Can you explain more? What do you mean by `comparing` here?

Comment: Compare the values of Array 1 [0] and Array 2 [0] and gives off a result of either Not available or Available and so on . Is it possible ?

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: What do you mean by "available" or "not available"? How is this related to Laravel in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both the arrays has same length, you can use for loop as below,

```
$temp = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1);$i++){
    $temp[] = (($array1[$i] >= $array2[$i]) ? 'Not Available': 'Available');
}
print_r($temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callback function along with `array_map` function like this.

```
<?php 

function getResult($first, $second)
{
    return $first > $second ? 'Available' : 'Not Available';
}

$firstArray = [1,4,5,6];
$secondArray = [2,3,1,9];

$data = array_map('getResult', $firstArray, $secondArray);

echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'<pre>';

?>
```

You can customize the logic inside the function for more complex logic as well. You can add any number of arrays as per your requirement. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something simple like this:

```
function compareArrays(array $array1, array $array2): array
    {
        $itemCount = (count($array1) > count($array2)) ? $array1 : $array2;
        $returnArray = [];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($itemCount); $i++) {
            $returnArray[] = ($array1 >= $array2) ? 'Avalible' : 'Not Avalible';
        }
        return $returnArray;
    }
```

Main reason being is we don't know from your post if the arrays will always be the same size so you have to compare them to get the larger of the two then use that for the loop. After that it's just simple comparisons.

Comment: Your generation of `$itemCount` is a bit longwinded (IMHO) - you could just use `$itemCount = max(count($array1), count($array2));`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using a simple for loop as bellow:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++){
  if($array1[$i] >= $array2[$i]){
    echo "Available"
  }else{
    echo "Not available";
  }
}
```

**Note** Here the two array must be of same size.

Answer (score 0):

If array1 and array2 is always same size, then easy solution

```
$data = [];
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($array2[$key])) { // for safety check for second array index bound
        break;
    }

    $data[] = $value >= $array2[$key] ? 'Not Available' : 'Available';
 }

return $data;
```